# BucketSort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort, bucket, bucket-sort

I'm trying to get my head round the bucketsorting algorithm, but failed to do so.

Looked at numerous examples... but can't get it working...

Let's say I have this:

```
public class Employee {
     int id; /// example: 52015
     String firstname,lastname;
     String department;

}
```

I have a huge list of employees, I then strip the list of all employees to sublists for each department. And the goal is to bucketsort these lists, on employee id. So I have my arraylists of employees, ready to pass on. I just can't seem to understand it.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bucket-sorting use `Comparable<Employee>` interface.

```
public class Employee implement Comparable<Employee> {
    int id; /// example: 52015
    String firstname,lastname;
    String department;

    public int compareTo(Employee compareEmployee) {
        return this.id - compareEmployee.getID();
    }
```

Anyway U can read [this](http://www.journaldev.com/780/java-comparable-and-comparator-example-to-sort-objects) article to understand this mechanism better.

Comment: Hi Александр Гончаренко,

This is the assignment i'm trying to complete:
use for the grouping on department and sorting on employee id a form of bucket-sort. Look at the department as bucket. 

Which I can't seem to figure out...  Though that rules out comparables?

Comment: @WordPressGuy, can U write example how do U want to sort. Because for this task (DB of employees) U need to create relational DB or create CRUD with observable pattern.

Comment: Hi, check this for some code: http://www.codeshare.io/OwcIc . I couldn't get it all in a comment.

Comment: @WordPressGuy, U can sort for any field in each bucket with comparator.